# printf() weird result in C

Tags: c

Here, my code gives weird results in the online **geeksforgeeks** compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        printf("\nhai\bas\rha\n");
}
```

**output:**  `haiasha`

but I think correct **output** is `haas`.

Online compiler ink : http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/paWwuv

Why compiler give wrong output? please help me.

Comment: It depends on how the standard output device responds to backspace and return characters, not the compiler.    The output is actually a sequence of characters `'\n', `'h'`, `'a'`, `'i'`, `'\b'`, etc  (i.e 11 characters), regardless of whether you see all of them on the particular output device.

Comment: `int main()`. Just `main()` is not valid C anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The online compiler prints to an html page, not to a console. `\b` is displayed differently by a browser than by a terminal window.

If you run the code in the online compiler, then view the page source you can see that all characters you print are there.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a compiler error. I would blame your terminal. Here is my output on a debian machine:

```
$ make so
cc     so.c   -o so
$ ./so 

haas
```

To be sure the program actually emits the charcode you expect, you can pipe the output to `xxd` for instance.

Also, if you return nothing, your `main` function should be `void`. When no type qualifier is used (which I find ugly), `int` return type is assumed.

Comment: "Also, if you return nothing, your main function should be void.". That's incorrect. Return type of `main` should be `int`, not `void`. And it should be explicitly declared as `int`, since there is no "implicit int" rule in C anymore. And you can safely "return nothing" from `main`, since the compiler will implicitly return `0` for you in such cases.

Comment: @AnT Right! I remember something related to main in the standard. But actually it was related to its arguments.
Do you have a ref on not having an implicit int anymore?

Comment: Well, if you open a copy of C99, at the very beginning it contains a list of major changes from C89/90. One of the items in that list explicitly mentions the abolition of "implicit int" rule. The rest of the standard text is modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks :)
I was peeking inside http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (quick google search, not the best obviously...)
The rationale (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) talks about that in 6.7.2 but for types. My point being: standard are (somehow) hard to get, and hard to read.

Comment: I was referring to the "Foreword" section of the document, which is present in n1256 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" output in this case is `\nhai\bas\rha\n`, exactly as you supplied it to `printf`, with `\n`, `\b` and `\r` standing for the corresponding special characters (or character combinations).

But how this output will look on a specific output device depends on the properties and capabilities of that device. It just so happens that the output device used (simulated) by your online compiler displays that sequence as `haiasha`.

It appears that your expectations are based on the behavior of a "typical" display terminal. Meanwhile, online compilers don't output anything directly to any "display". They intercept the standard output and then postprocess it for representation on a Web page. What you see is the result of that postprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

[`\b`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace) is a special character. The terminals usually interpret it as "move the caret one character to the left". As a consequence the next printed character overwrites the last character printed before `\b`.

However, in other contexts the `\b` character may be interpreted in a different way. For example, in a file it is nothing but a regular byte (with value `8`).